# Long polling with Qt

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I need to get real time information from my server to my Qt program.
I'm actualy doing that by creating a connection to the database and then fetch data every second.

I'm looking for a better solution to do that: avoiding fetching data in a infinite loop.

Best solution would be to make a MySQL request and only have a callback when new data arrived in the database. Like a Ajax long polling connection, but with Qt in c++

Comment: Most perverted sounding title of the day.

Comment: What do you mean? I don't know the name used of long serveur connexions in c++... if it exists

Answer (score 1):

Don't fetch the data every second. The efficient solution is [Websocket](https://www.websocket.org/) technology. It is your server to push data to your client and you can use [QWebSocket](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwebsocket.html) class with Qt starting version 5.3. There is a nice [example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/echoclient.html).

But this solution is definitely to implement on both server and client. I have actually implemented such client functionality lately and that is not really complex with Qt but the solution depends on server specifics and we do ping-pong with the server after each 50 seconds to prevent the socket from closing. But that can depend on concrete server side websocket implementation.